# wso2 integration with orion and Authzforce and access control

Tags: wso2, fiware-orion, authzforce, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server

Good, I would like to create a scenario where Orion has several entities, and from a request to WSO2 to check that the user or agent has authorization with a series of policies. And in case it has authorization redirect the WSO2 request to Orion.
Would it be possible and how?

Would it be possible to integrate as PIP of Authzforce to WSO2?

Thank you!!

Comment: What is OWS2? Do you mean WSO2?

Comment: sorry, yes, is WSO2

Comment: OK, which WSO2 product are you talking about? Identity Server? Application Server? API manager? ...

Comment: I would like to use WSO2 API Manager to be able to create data instance or get instance. But to be able to create instances or get data, I want to evaluate the policies according to the role of the user who wants to perform these operations. And, of course, the API that I would use would be similar to Orion, as they would be POST and GET requests for information. What I am looking for is to secure these requests by looking at the time of the requests, the role of the user, etc... If you think that my current question is better to ask it privately, I could talk to you individually?

Comment: I am talking about Identity Server and API Manager

Comment: also, my idea is to make requests to orion but secure those requests through roles using WSO2 Identity server.

Comment: From my understanding, the WSO2 API manager would be the PEP sending XACML requests to AuthzForce PDP. In the requests, there will be the user ID, action (HTTP method), etc. and you want AuthzForce to get the user roles from WSO2 Identity Server in order to evaluate the role-based access control policy. So do you know how to get the roles from WSO2 Identity Server? Which API call? then we know how to implement the attribute provider (PIP) in AuthzForce (see https://github.com/authzforce/core/wiki/Attribute-Providers )